# Why does JSON.parse("string") fail

Tags: json

According to the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) a string is a legitimate JSON value.

[image]

So why does this happen?

Comment: This happens when the json is not in the correct format. For JSON.parse to work the string should be in correct format. Post you json for a clearer ans.

Comment: I did. It's in the image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are actually passing the bare word `string` in to the the function which of course is not valid JSON. To actually pass in the *value* `"string`" you need to be careful with your JavaScript.

Try this:

```
JSON.parse("\"string\"")
```

The extra pair of quotes must be escaped so they become part of the value you pass in to the function.

Comment: I don't know, but I can explain the first upvote quite completely.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you could refer to actual spec for proof. JSONString is valid, which can be seen from "15.12.1.2 The JSON Syntactic Grammar" at [ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

Comment: @eis Syntactic subtleties call for official standard references, but this is kind of broad strokes.

Comment: The OP linked to the spec himself. His error was simply with his JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax error tells you: "s" is an unexpected token. A string is a valid JSON value but as the spec describes it must be enclosed in double quotes.

```
string
  ""
  " chars "
```

Generally, you can use `JSON.stringify(myValue)` to check what a properly formatted JSON string of such value would be.

Answer (score 0):

Because a string in JSON must be surrounded by quotation marks, and in your   `JSON.parse("string")` call, `JSON.parse` never "sees" any quotation marks as part of the text it is asked to parse.  The double-quotes that we see are being used to form a legal string to pass in -- they're not part of the *text* we're passing in.

This call works:

```
JSON.parse('"s"')
```

Comment: Why this fails: `JSON.parse('"aa\"bb"')` ? How to escape double quote inside?