# How to get data from response? Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am very new to node js. I am just testing some stuff about client-server communication.

I have these codes:

```
server:

app.post('/zsa', (req, res) => {
    res.send("zsamo");
});
```

```
client:

fetch("http://localhost:3000/zsa", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

With this code i get a response object:

[image]

I want to log to the console what was in the response data: "zsamo"

Comment: The fetch() returns a Response object. You need to transform the body into JSON data by adding a then after fetch: fetch( ... ).then( res => res.json() ).then( data => ...

Comment: Beware that `zsamo` is not JSON

Comment: @jabaa The quotes are not being transmitted in the original code (`res.send("zsamo")`).  Beware that `JSON.parse("zsamo")` in a modern browser will still produce *SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'z', "zsamo" is not valid JSON*  But `JSON.parse('"zsamo"')` will result in a string with the content: `zsamo`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18096141/1563833)

Comment: @Wyck Yes, you are right. `zsamo` is not JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` returns a *Response*.  If you want JSON from the body of your response then you can do this:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

See also [Using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: [Technically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#return_value), it returns a _Promise that resolves to a Response object_.

Comment: And how can i just display "zsamo", what was in the response data?

Comment: @Barta you can use `response.text()` instead of `response.json()` and don't send your response from the server with the Content-Type  `application/json` but instead use `text/plain`

Comment: ...or you could have transmitted your response as a **quoted** string, which **is** valid JSON:  `res.send('"zsamo"')`

Answer (score 0):

At client side, in console.log instead of data, write data.body